# Проблема с вёрсткой на странице профиля

Tags: дефект, профиль-участника

Проблема с длинным адресом.

Вот профиль: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/235775/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%8f

Вот проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Куда смотреть-то? На имя участника? Для таких целей тут принято красными кругами от руки рисовать :) Кстати, баг уже был подобный описан на MSE при длинном поле location.

Comment: @älёxölüt ну вроде и так понятно, что длинный адрес контент смещает) Думал и так понятно)

Comment: Понятно, если вглядываться несколько секунд. Но можно было бы и выделить, чтобы сразу понять. Вот, кстати, [баг на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318125/339911), один из, там на картинке всё помечено :)

Comment: Там не только с адресом проблемы. Во многих местах вёрстка едет из-за длинных строк. Не научились они к 2018 году обрезать их. Зато в очереди вместо того, чтоб нормальную вёрстку сделать, обрезают ОДНО слово.